# How can I include another Makefile from a target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Makefile:

```
include:
    wget <tarball with another Makefile>.tar.gz
    tar -zxvf <tarball with another Makefile>.tar.gz
    include Makefile.from_tarball
    echo ${VAR_ONLY_EXIST_IN_TARBALL_MAKEFILE}
```

I would like to do like the above where i want to include a Makefile upon running a target

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html

Comment: Yes, but what for? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Beta the question is the problem im trying to solve. within the include target where i m downloading a tarball, i want to print a make var from a Makefile from the tarball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include another makefile in GNU make with an `include` command at the top level:

```
-include foobar.mak
```

If you put a dash in front of it (as above), that will not give an error and will instead defer loading the makefile on demand.  If that makefile has any dependencies, GNU make will first make sure they're up to date and will reread the makefile if necessary once they are updated

```
foobar.mak: foobar.tar.gz
        tar xf $< $@    # extract the makefile

foobar.tar.gz:
        wget <URL for tarball>
```

these rules will download the tarball (if it hasn't been downloaded yet), extract the makefile (if the tarball is newer) and then include it.

Comment: oh let me try that, thank you!